# Delay after back button is pressed

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

When the back button is pressed on some pages, there is a short delay (1-5 seconds) before the NavigationStart event is even triggered.

I'm using the Angular RouterExtensions back() function.

At first I thought it was the loading of data on the previous page, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. THe page before does have a ListView with about 7 ng-templates, but it only loads 20 items at a time, and the data is quite small.

It seems to work ok when I remove some of the ng-templates, suggesting that it is to do with that. Unfortunately all of these templates are needed.

I can't really provide an example because my project is massive, and new projects aren't "big" enough to have the error.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction

Comment: @Robertgarcia As much as I'd love to, my project is a year old containing hundreds of components. And I can't reproduce it on a new project - yet starting again isn't an option.

Any tips on how I can debug it myself at least?

Comment: I can only suggest to add some timer functions inside `ngOnInit` `ngOnDestroy` of the components you are going back to and coming from. This might give you an idea where the delay comes from. Also what happens if you double click the back button? Have you tried to use the google profiler to see what your app is doing in those seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a render timeout for your view - see #2 for full details here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4782

This ensures the navigation completes before your UI renders and makes stuff much smoother (especially on Android).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing significant delay ~+ 5 seconds, turns out it was due to:

> changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush